# Get value of arraylist in the arraylist to write listview in Android

Tags: android, listview, arraylist

I just created a city object with other essential things like tourist places. I used arraylist in the Arraylist .

There is any object in the arrayslist .Here is the code below.

MainActivity

```
City city = new City();

        city.setCityName("London");
        city.setmCityImageResourceId(R.drawable.london);

        AttactivePlaces londonAttactivePlaces_one =new AttactivePlaces();
        londonAttactivePlaces_one.setPlaceName("Big Ben");
        londonAttactivePlaces_one.setmAttaticePlaceImageResourceId(R.drawable.bigben);
        londonAttactivePlaces_one.setPlaceDetailInformation("Big Ben");
        city.getAttactivePlaces().add(londonAttactivePlaces_one);

gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
                   switch (position){

                   case 0:
                           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),position+"",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,AttactivePlacesActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("position",position);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        break;

                    case 1:
                                                  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),position+"",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Intent intent1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this,AttactivePlacesActivity.class);
                        intent1.putExtra("position",position);
                        startActivity(intent1);
                        break;
```

AttractivePlacesActivity

```
Intent mIntent = getIntent();
        Bundle bundle = mIntent.getExtras();

        int position = bundle.getInt("position");



        AttractivePlacesAdapter attractivePlacesAdapter = new AttractivePlacesAdapter(this,cityAttactivePlaces,R.color.mainBackground,position);
```

I get Oth value of the attactive places but how I can get all values of Attactive Places in android

Here is the adapter code below.

```
public class AttractivePlacesAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<City> {

    private int mBackgroundColor; // BackGround Color For each Activity

    private int gridviewPosition;

public AttractivePlacesAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<City> resources, int color,int position) {
    // Here, we initialize the ArrayAdapter's internal storage for the context and the list.
    // the second argument is used when the ArrayAdapter is populating a single TextView.
    // Because this is a custom adapter for two TextViews , the adapter is not
    // going to use this second argument, so it can be any value. Here, we used 0.
    // 0 -> list item layout resource ID
    super(context,0 ,resources);
    mBackgroundColor = color;
    gridviewPosition = position;
}

    // get list item from getView

    /**
     * Provides a view for an AdapterView (ListView, GridView, etc.)
     *
     * @param position The position in the list of data that should be displayed in the
     *                 list item view.
     * @param convertView The recycled view to populate.
     * @param parent The parent ViewGroup that is used for inflation.
     * @return The View for the position in the AdapterView.
     */
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        // Check if the existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
        View listview = convertView;
        if (listview == null) {
            // parent -> listView   false -> we don't want to attach list item to parent
            listview = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout, parent, false);
        }

      // get position of item to city
    //City city = getItem(gridviewPosition);

    City city = MainActivity.cityArraylist.get(gridviewPosition);

        // City Information
        TextView name = (TextView) listview.findViewById(R.id.bilgi_text_view);
        name.setText(city.getAttactivePlaces().get(position).getPlaceName());


        // Picture of City
        ImageView image = (ImageView) listview.findViewById(R.id.image_image_view);

        // Check whether the picture is or not.
        if (city.hasImage()) {
            //
            image.setImageResource(city.getAttactivePlaces().get(position).getmAttaticePlaceImageResourceId());
        } else {
            image.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }




        // Set theme color for the list item
        View textContainer = listview.findViewById(R.id.text_container);

        // Find the color that the resource ID maps to
        int color = ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), mBackgroundColor);

        // Set Background color to view
        textContainer.setBackgroundColor(color);

        return listview;

    }

}
```

The error

How could I solve it out. Thanks

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                     Process: com.example.android.guide, PID: 5056
                                                                                       java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 1
                                                                                           at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
                                                                                           at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
                                                                                           at com.example.android.guide.AttractivePlacesAdapter.getView(AttractivePlacesAdapter.java:63)
```

Comment: try city.getAttactivePlaces().get(position).getPlaceName()

Comment: I tried it before . This code is shown just only 0 position . Other objects in the arraylist can not be shown.

Comment: Can you post the code for the AttractivePlaces class and the getAttractivePlaces method?

Answer (score 0):

Replace 0 with position.

```
name.setText(city.getAttactivePlaces().get(position).getPlaceName());
```

Comment: kiran, I've undeleted your answer. You are fine to re-post "answers" posted as comments (although we often repost them with the "community wiki" box checked). For more info, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251597/.

Answer (score 0):

By getting the value I think you want to get the `List` of `AttactivePlaces` which is contained in an `Object` called `City`.

You can achieve that using `foreach` or `for`like :

```
List<AttractivePlaces> places = new ArrayList<>();
for (AttractivePlaces item:
        getItem(position).getAttractivePlaces){
    places.add(item);
}
```

or

```
List<AttractivePlaces> places = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i == 0; i < getItem(position).getAttractivePlaces().size; i++) {
    places.add(getItem(position).getAttractivePlaces().get(i));
}
```

Those 2 basically iterates the `AttractivePlaces` Object in an Object called `City` in position x, to obtain all of the values in `AttractivePlaces` and store them in a new `List` called `places`.

EDIT :

Are you trying to do this : User is given a menu on places to click which is saved in an `Object` called `City` and when user clicks it, the adapter gets populated with the `AttractivePlaces` arraylist taken from the `City` Object? If yes..

First declare a new `ArrayList` as your item type and change your item type in the `Adapter` to that same type like..

```
public class AttractiveAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<AttractivePlaces> {
    private List<AttractivePlaces> mDataset = new ArrayList<>();
    private Context context;

    public class AttractiveAdapter (Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    // Here you can freely change the dataset on user click
    public void changeDataset (List<AttractivePlaces> newItems) {
        if(mDataset.size() > 0){
            mDataset.clear();
        }
        mDataset.addAll(newItems);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ...

        // Check whether the picture is or not.
        if (city.hasImage()) {
            //
            image.setImageResource(mDataset.get(position).getmAttaticePlaceImageResourceId());
        } else {
            image.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mDataset.size();
    }
}
```

Comment: I just used iterator to get all values . I put textview and image view in the for loop. Then I run the app, it shows only last element of list. But I want all values of arraylist in the listview.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here actually? What I am seeing by the code is, there are items which user can click, then that item has its own list inside it, correct?

Comment: Yes.  I only just got first element of arraylist by using name.setText(city.getAttactivePlaces().get(0).getPlaceName()); as you can see but I want to try how to get all values.

Comment: So you wish to get all the `attractivePlaces` in the item user clicked, right? << Nevermind this, I'm re reading your code

Comment: Get all values in the item which user clicked or what? if yes, my written code would work well, please explain more

Comment: Your code would work well but When I use for loop with textview and imageview, the last element of arraylist is shown in the listview as you know.  How do I return listview after getting all values. Where do I use for loop in the getView method.

Comment: Hmm.. Here, so basically you're trying to get Attractive places like Big Ben,  London Eye, etc. and place it in another list? Or are you trying to get all the attractive places from all the cities you have like all places from London, all places from Japan, all places from Rio?

Comment: I tried to do this. How do I use loop in getview Method.

Comment: I tried it but nothing changed .I just want to show list item of arraylist in the object when city.getAttactivePlaces().get(0).getPlaceName() and name.setText(city.getAttactivePlaces().get(0).getPlaceName()) are assigned . The issue comes from get() method. Although I use for loop and other iterator , the issue has still there. How can I fix get() method .

Comment: When they are assigned? I still don't get what is your requirement, sorry. The method itself shouldn't be an issue, the issue comes from how it is used. Your problem is getting only the last value right? Do you have `public int getCount()` method overriden? Check my last line in the last code

Comment: City's position comes from its position in the previous intent as a gridview. City's arraylist is shown in the shown AttractivePlacesActivity.  Before I use iterator , position is got from city's position in the gridview. İt's ok. However, when a for loop is finished, it is shown last element of arraylist. for loop overwrites textview and imageview themselves. I want to show values of arraylist in the listview. Check my last code(for loop).

Comment: Is it possible to write an activity related with  AttractiveAdapter. It is enough for me to create AttractivePlaces Object and AttractiveAdapter object and add it to listview. Thank you.

Comment: @DRF Bro, check out my edited code, thats an Adapter which can be used in the `AttractivePlacesActivity`, it doesn't have `foreach` loop, it is based on position. You will only need to pass your `AttractivePlaces` object to that Activity. If you use for, each position in the `listView` will be the same, because a for loop should have an end and the end will always be the same each position. Have you tried my code?

Comment: Bro, I tried to get position of gridview and it listed with its content in the first position. Other positions occur an issue. I shared my last edited code. Please check it out. Thanks.

Comment: How did you initialize your adapter? Show me the code of `onClick` when user clicks on one of the item from the adapter before this adapter. I've never used that kind of constructor before, normally I pass the list manually and store it in the adapter manually.

Comment: I sent position to from mainactivity to another activity then created an object with constructor and put it into the object.

Comment: Oh so you only send the position? Show how you use for to iterate the objects to be inserted into the adapter, especially this part `new AttractivePlacesAdapter(this,cityAttactivePlaces,R.color.mainBackground,position);` that `cityAttractivePlaces` part